# Connecting to a MySQL Database and do a query using only client side Javascript and HTA

Tags: javascript, mysql, hta

In a HTA application, how to connect to a MySQL database using JavaScript ONLY and do a query in it? No VBScript and no third parties like node.js, just JavaScript.

Comment: You have a MySQL environment to deploy, including the binaries. So, you can use `mysql.exe` utiliy to execute queries and store the result (as CSV files for example) on the file system, the way as you did with PHP. You know the rest.

Comment: The question is pretty simple, can I avoid using VBScript and only use JavaScript to access my local MySQL database. I know there are many utilities and work-arrounds. I want to know if I can do what VBScript does with an ODBC driver but with JavaScript instead.

Comment: In Windows Scripting (which HTA relies on) the thecnology and the API is the same regardless of the language used. So, yes you can use JScript instead.

Comment: So how would I go into creating a connection to the MySQL database with Javascript, send the search query and loop through the recordset like one would do with an ODBC connection in VBScript?

Comment: Yes is yes. For the rest: https://www.google.com/search?q=jscript+ado+connection

Comment: OF COURSE!!! I Completely forgot about ADO. I was concentrating on ODBC. Damn the hours I spent for nothing searching incorrectly. Thank you @Kul-Tigin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HUGE thanks to [Kul-Tigin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893670/kul-tigin) for providing the answer for the USE of ADO ActiveX which I did not even think about. I was not searching properly the ODBC connection methods and always fell on VBScript. So here is a working code of a personal test I did after installing the latest MySQL ODBC Connector as of the date of this comment.

```
var hmess = document.getElementById("mess");
var oconn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var ors = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
var sconn = "";
var scn_driver = "DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver;";
var scn_server = "SERVER=localhost;";
var scn_database = "DATABASE=DatabaseName;";
var scn_userid = "USER ID=UserName;";
var scn_password = "PASSWORD=UserPassword;";
var ssql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE IDField=1";

sconn = scn_driver + scn_server + scn_database + scn_userid + scn_password;

oconn.Open(sconn);
ors.Open(ssql,oconn);
ors.MoveFirst();
hmess.innerHTML = ors("TableFieldName");
ors.Close();
oconn.Close();
```

Thank you for the answers and your help.